# How to cite more than one papers using the AAAI style

Tags: bibliographies

I am using the [AAAI style](http://www.aaai.org/Publications/Author/author.php) to prepare my manuscript.

Ive found that every time when I cite more than one papers, the later one will always become a question mark. Like the following

```
 \cite{cortes1995support, chang2011libsvm}
```

It turns out to be

> (**Cortes 1995;?**)

But if I cite it separately, they are all fine. That is if I replace the code by the following

```
 \cite{cortes1995support} and \cite{chang2011libsvm}
```

It turns out to be

> (**Cortes 1995**) and (**Chang 2011**)

Does this means the style do not support citing more than one paper at the same time?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Does your document load a citation management package such as `natbib`?

Comment: @Mico Thanks for your warm welcome. About your question, no I didn't.

Comment: It works for me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/aRJFN.png Please provide a MWE to help us to help you.

Comment: @Mico `aaai` isn't compatible with `natbib`.

Comment: @HarishKumar I do also tried on a MWE, it works. I think the style is conflicted with some of my code. Do you have any idea what will make this happens?

Comment: How do I? ;-) That is why we ask for a MWE. :-)

Comment: @HarishKumar Finally I have solved the problem, no space is allowed between two citations...

Answer (score 16):

Ive just figured out the problem: No spaces is allowed between two citation labels.

Means that in this case

```
\cite{cortes1995support, chang2011libsvm}
```

problem will be caused and the output becomes:

> (Cortes 1995;?)

But if the space is removed, it works fine.

```
\cite{cortes1995support,chang2011libsvm}
```

> (**Cortes 1995**, **Chang 2011**)